# Like and count make sql server processor 100%

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with count and like, this is my sql query

```
SELECT * 
,(CASE  
        WHEN all_trx.trx_gagal = 0 THEN 100 
        WHEN all_trx.trx_sukses = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE CAST(all_trx.trx_sukses*100.0 / all_trx.trx_total as numeric(18,2) )
 END) AS persen_sukses
,(CASE 
        WHEN all_trx.trx_sukses = 0 THEN 100 
        WHEN all_trx.trx_gagal = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE CAST(all_trx.trx_gagal*100.0 / all_trx.trx_total as numeric(18,2) )
    END) AS persen_gagal  
FROM 
(
SELECT TOP 10
    transaksi.kode_produk AS Produk, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN outbox.pesan LIKE '%SUCCESS%'THEN 1 END) AS trx_sukses, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN outbox.pesan LIKE '%FAIL%'THEN 1 END) AS trx_gagal, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN outbox.status >= '20' THEN 1 END) AS trx_total 
FROM outbox INNER JOIN transaksi ON transaksi.kode = outbox.kode_transaksi
WHERE CAST(transaksi.tgl_entri AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)  
GROUP BY transaksi.kode_produk
)  AS all_trx
```

[image]

I need count the  message, I take string SUCCESS and FAIL for count every message.
The goals is I can get percentage of success and fail. Maybe any suggestion for this problem because I'm just learning sql :D

Comment: Are you *sure* it's the count and not the fact you are `CAST`ing your column `transaksi.tgl_entri` to a `date` in the `WHERE`? What happens if you use proper date boundaries with `>=` and `<`?

Comment: Suggested reading: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/140734)

Comment: Also, using a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a bad habit; it'll result in 10 arbitrary rows being returned and which rows those are could be different **every time** the query is run.

Comment: Table schemas and execution plan, please!

Comment: `outbox.status >= '20'` will return FALSE for `'199'`, at least if outbox.status  is a character type column. And TRUE for `'3'`.

Comment: Top 10 with no order by... so a random top 10 then?

Comment: But what is your actual problem? Why do you appear to want the machine to NOT use as much processor power as possible to get your work done? Are the values generated by your query incorrect? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

LIKE operator that begin with a wildchar (%') will not be SARGABLE, and need to read char by char into the strings that needs to be scanned. It is why the processor is widely used.

SARGABLE is an acronym for Search ARGument ABLE. A predicate (boolean expression in the WHERE or HAVING clause) is SARGABLE, when, and only when, it can use indexes. Indexes can be use in those typical cases :

- AColumn = AValue
- AColumn < AValue
- AColumn <= AValue
- AColumn > AValue
- AColumn >= AValue
- AColumn LIKE 'AValue%'

Because indexes ordered the "pure" values (like a dictionnary) the above predicates cannot use an index :

- AColumn <> AValue
- AColumn LIKE '%AValue'